# GUI for creating fullscreen web applications

Tags: user-interface, fullscreen, rad

Desktop GUI builder tools such as [Qt Designer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/designer-manual.html) and [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) let me easily design a resizable interface with menus, shortcuts, tab order, status bar, etc

Is there an equivalent tool for the web?

I am not after building a typical web interface where you scroll down to view all the content, but a ***fullscreen*** interface with menus at the top and status bar at bottom.

Here is an (awesome) example fullscreen web app: http://desktop.sonspring.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash Platform would probably give you a more familiar environment to develop for. The [Flex framework](http://flex.org/) provides a complete framework for developing sophisticated applications and [Flex Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex) (built on top of Eclipse) gives a UI 'designer' to build large parts of your app using the drag & drop philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

For the kind of interfaces you're describing, [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com) is quite a nice library.  While there is not a GUI interface designer yet, there is reportedly one in the pipeline.

While the widget library is available under GPL3 (which caused some controversy), it's also available via commercial licenses.  The interface builder will cost some kind of money.

Check out the demos, there is a desktop sample very similar to the one you referenced in your question.

Comment: here it is: http://www.extjs.com/blog/2009/10/08/ext-js-designer-preview/
Looks very promising.